# По поисковым запросам и релевантности

Tags: html, seo

Я ввожу Jahonts в поиск по латвии и мне выводит столбец с отделами сайта, адресом ,верменем работы и телефоном . Kак добится того же на своём сайте ?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте свою организацию в Google.Мой бизнес https://business.google.com
Там же добавите расположение на карте, часы работы, фотографии и дополнительные сведения

Для яндекса сделайте то же самое в Yandex.Справочник https://yandex.ru/sprav/companies